# How to initiate a truely asynchronous function with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am learning Kotlin coroutines.  I have a situation where I want to execute some sign-in stuff when a user clicks a sign-in button.  I don't want this to block the app, it will display a progress spinner until the sign-in activity is complete but the user should be free to move around and the UI update (in fact I'd like text on the progess spinner to update depending on the stage).

However, the only way it seems possible to launch a coroutine is from within a `runBlocking` element, which essentially invalidates the asynchronous nature.

My use case:

```
 binding.loginSignIn.setOnClickListener{ signIn(it) }
```

On sign in click, exectute this function

```
private fun signIn(view : View) {
    // Do some data validation
    if (!isValidEmail(model.email.value)) {
        app.messenger.showSnackBar(R.string.login_enter_email, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
        return
    }
    if (model.pwd.value == null || model.pwd.value!!.isEmpty()) {
        app.messenger.showSnackBar(R.string.login_enter_pwd, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
        return
    }

    // Show the progress spinner
    model.showProgress.value = true

    runBlocking {
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            try {
                // Talk to server, talk to data storage and synchronise some data  
            } catch (e: ServerException) {
                app.messenger.showSnackBar(e.message, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                app.messenger.showSnackBar(e.message, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
            }finally{
                 // allows to call a function like a 'callback' ?
            }
        }
    }
    // This now waits until the coroutine above completes
```

I don't want this function to wait.  I want the onClick event to end and return control.

What I want is to give the coroutine a callback function, that executes once the coroutine has completed.  I could even call one myself in the `finally` block above that I assume would result in the same sort of behaviour.

This is basic `async` `await` type behaviour but I can't figure out from the documentation how to break out of the runBlocking while awaiting the end of the coroutine?

I have looked at `GlobalScope.launch` but that is riven with warnings about not alerting when complete or errors - which is not what I want.

If I try to simply use `launch` it has to be within a coroutine scope already, so from what I can see runBlocking seems to be the only allowable outer layer for coroutines.  I am clearly fundamentally misunderstanding something about how coroutines work / what they're for, can someone please explain?

Comment: [Use `lifecycleScope` on your activity `lifecycle` or your fragment's `viewLifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines).

Comment: @CommonsWare haha, thankyou, yes, I was just typing out an answer having just found this - funny how just writing a question can open up new investigation! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hours of looking, ask a question, and five minutes later find an answer.

The answer appears to be `LifecycleScope.launch{}`

Still not sure about the callback, but adding a function call to `finally` seems to do the job **please someone add an answer if there is a better way of handling this**.

So I have ended up with:

```
private fun signIn(view : View) {
    // Do some data validation
    if (!isValidEmail(model.email.value)) {
        app.messenger.showSnackBar(R.string.login_enter_email, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
        return
    }
    if (model.pwd.value == null || model.pwd.value!!.isEmpty()) {
        app.messenger.showSnackBar(R.string.login_enter_pwd, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
        return
    }

    // Show the progress spinner
    model.showProgress.value = true

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            try {
                // Talk to server, talk to data storage and synchronise some data  
            } catch (e: ServerException) {
                app.messenger.showSnackBar(e.message, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                app.messenger.showSnackBar(e.message, view, Messenger.TYPE_WARNING)
            }finally{
                 concludeSignIn(valuea, valueb)
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun concludeSignIn(countA : Int,countB : Int){
    // Do final checks and remove progress bar
}
```

Added link provided by @CommonsWare to the answer:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines